# Shopware 6 Security Plugin - compilation error

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using Shopware 6 Security Plugin installed via composer (Shopware store). After update to 1.0.16 version I have problem with compilation. Now, I can't compile administration panel. I have 6.4.14 SW version.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cookie-storage' in '/home/coffedesk/apps/development/vendor/store.shopware.com/swagplatformsecurity/src/Resources/app/administration/src/init'
```

Comment: Sounds like something you should report to Shopware's issue tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run inside that plugin npm install. If you use the production template, make sure you have jq installed. So the dependencies gets automatically installed

https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/6.4/bin/build-administration.sh#L23